# crawlspider not crawling using urls in text files

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, forum

Problem Statement:

I have a list of forum urls in a file names myurls.csv in each line as follows:

```
https://www.drupal.org/user/3178461/track
https://www.drupal.org/user/511008/track
```

I wrote a CrawlSpider code to crawl the forum posts as follows:

```
class fileuserurl(CrawlSpider):
    name = "fileuserurl"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/user/\d/track'),
    restrict_xpaths = ('//li[@class="pager-next"]',),
    canonicalize=False ),callback='parse_page',follow=True)
    )

    def __init__(self):
    f = open('./myurls.txt','r').readlines()
    self.allowed_domains = ['www.drupal.org']
    self.start_urls = [l.strip() for l in f]
    super(fileuserurl,self).__init__()

    def parse_page(self, response):
    print '*********** START PARSE_PAGE METHOD**************'
    # print response.url
    items = response.xpath("//tbody/tr")
    myposts=[]
    for temp in items:
    item = TopicPosts()
    item['topic'] = temp.xpath(".//td[2]/a/text()").extract()
    relative_url = temp.xpath(".//td[2]/a/@href").extract()[0]
    item['topiclink'] = 'https://www.drupal.org'+relative_url
    item['author'] = temp.xpath(".//td[3]/a/text()").extract()
    try:
    item['replies'] = str(temp.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").extract()[0]).strip('\n')
    except:
    continue
    myposts.append(item)
    return myposts
```

Question:

It only gives me the first page output of the urls mentioned in my text file. I want to go to every link of the pages as defined by next in the front page.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: alecxe,the indents are correct in my editor(pycharm), its only error while copying in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, define [`start_requests()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests):

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open('./myurls.txt','r') as f:
        for url in f:
            url = url.strip()
            yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

And, you need to have your `rules` defined as an iterable. Plus, the regular expression inside `allow` should allow more than a single digit (`\d+` instead of `\d`):

```
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='/user/\d+/track', restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="pager-next"]', canonicalize=False),
         callback='parse_page',
         follow=True)
]
```

Comment: the method parse_page is not being called. when i replace it will parse then only the crawling is done and only first page of the urls in the file. (As mentioned in scrapy document we shouldn't use parse method for CrawlSpider so i avoided that) Your start_requests function also doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks for your updated code. But it only worked from the second page. All the first pages of urls are skipped... Am I missing something ???

Comment: @LearnByExample could it be that there is no links on the first page? Thank you.

Comment: Dear @alecxe  , There is link in the very first page you can check there is link //li[@class="pager-next"]' in first page of https://www.drupal.org/user/3178461/track using firefox 'Inspect in Firepath' feature...

Comment: @LearnByExample this is what I mean - I'm getting "No content available" in the page.

Comment: You can check the url https://www.drupal.org/user/511008/track and use xslt expression as  //li[@class="pager-next"] . It has two pages currently but scraping will only start from page 2 (https://www.drupal.org/user/511008/track?page=1) ...